# Having both Anaconda Navigator and Python 3. installed

Tags: python, anaconda

Is it ok having both Anaconda Navigator and Python 3. installed?

I went through stack overflow and there were questions about having both Anacondas 2.7 and 3.5 but nothing related to my question.

I find it easier to use python idle for the basic easy codes and I know I can use idle using anaconda prompt - idle but I sill want to install python 3. from python.org

In this case, will having installed both anaconda navigator and python 3. cause any problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that won't be an issue at all but please remind that in environment variables please keep only conada or python 3 paths. sometimes it will cause you an error.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Are you talking about Environment Variable - Path? I thought I could add as many as paths I could?

Comment: yes im talking about environment variables. if you are using pip3 install to install packages by keeping in mind that it will go to your standard python but it doesn't work like that it will go to conda environment whatever the first configuration you have given OS will take the first environment variable as the default one you cannot switch between

Comment: Um.. so you are saying that if I have installed Anaconda first then Python 3.7, and I want to install packages for my Python 3.7 using CMD - PIP install, it's not installing it on my python 3.7 environment but it will install in conda environment?

Comment: Exactly. My suggestion is to install packages in conda using UI and let the command lint interact with python 3.7

Comment: I do not understand what it means to " let the command lint interact with python 3.7". Is there any way I could do that? Link for an instruction would be helpful. Appreciate your comments.